# Chrome Browser: How to make enter key work to follow URLs

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to follow URLs in Chrome without having to use the mouse? In Firefox, I can search for text (using ctrl-G) and then once found, hit enter right away to follow the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tab between elements... press enter to follow links.  You can also search for text by using control-F and typing whatever you're looking for... after finding whatever you're looking for... hit escape to close the search box & press enter to select it.

Comment: I guess I was missing the escape. Not as convenient but works. thanks